# Laravel Auth attempt not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

First i created the Admin model in which i implemented it using Authenticable Admin.php

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

    class Admin extends Model implements \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
    {
        //
        use Authenticatable;
    }
```

then i created the migration :

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->string('email');
                $table->string('password');
            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::drop('admins');
        }
    }
```

Replaced the Users model in config/auth.php with Admin Model :

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
```

AdminController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller{

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $posts= Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3)->get();
        return view('backend.index')->with(['posts'=>$posts]);
    }

    public function getLogin(){
        return view('backend.login');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email'=>'required|email',
            'password'=>'required'
        ]);

        dd(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['email'],'password'=>$request['password']]));

        if(!Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['email'],'password'=>$request['password']])){
            return redirect()->back()->with(['fail'=>'Could Not Log You In']);
        }

        return redirect()->route('admin.index');
    }

    public function getLogout(){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('blog.index');
    }

}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/admin/login',[
    'uses'=>'AdminController@getLogin',
    'as'=>'admin.login'
]);

Route::post('/admin/login',[
    'uses'=>'AdminController@postLogin',
    'as'=>'admin.login'
]);
```

login.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Admin Area</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    @yield('styles')
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @include('includes.info-box')
        <form method="post" action="{{route('admin.login')}}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
                       {{$errors->has('email')?'class=alert alert-danger':'' }}
                       value="{{Request::old('email')}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password: </label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"
                       {{$errors->has('password')?'class=alert alert-danger':'' }}
                       >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

so when i tried to login and dd the Auth Attempt it is returning false i have a user with email test@123.com and password test :
[image]

created the user using seeder :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class AdminTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //
        $admin = new \App\Admin;
        $admin->email='test@123.com';
        $admin->password='test@123.com';
        $admin->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you encrypt the password using bcrypt?

Comment: no because the password is simple text

Comment: Auth attempt bcrypts the entered password, so if you registered the user and did not used bcrypt to encrypt the password, it will fail. try $user->password = bcrypt('test');

Comment: where should i use it

Comment: when registering your user, or you can change your user's password in tinker:
$u = App\Admin::first();
$u->password = bcrypt('test');
$u->save()

Comment: Auth::attempt hashes the password passed to it, so when registering the users, you also need to hash their passwords.

Comment: i have created user using seeder method let me add that code also

Comment: your password is test@123.com?

Comment: no that's the editing mistake i have corrected it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So for your seeder.

```
$admin = new \App\Admin;
$admin->email='test@123.com';
$admin->password='test@123.com';
$admin->save();
```

the password should be hashed using bcrypt.

```
$admin->password = bcrypt('test@123.com');
```

but as you've said, you're trying 'test' as the password, so it should be:

```
$admin->password = bcrypt('test');
```

that should work.

the reason is, Auth::attempt hashes the entered password using bcrypt.
So if the stored password in your database is not bcrypt-ed, Auth::attempt
will fail to match the two passwords.

For example you put test as the password, plain text, if you try to login to laravel using Auth::attempt using password = 'test', string 'test' will be compared against the bcrpyt version of 'test'.

Comment: but it's saying bcrypt mehod not found when i used command db:seed

Comment: i wonder why! it should work, i know bcrypt is a method of php.

Comment: what email and password are you trying to enter? please update your seeder so i can see

Comment: you're still using test@123.com as password

Comment: oh yes sorry i used test@123.com this time and it worked